# Missing Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate cmdlet in new Sharepoint module PnP.PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am relying on the Powershell cmdlet *Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate* to automate deployment of Sharepoint-Templates to new sites.

Have always used the ["SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline"](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline) Powershell module where it exists, but when importing it, it said that it's about to be retired.

> WARNING:  You are running the legacy version of PnP PowerShell. This
> version will be archived soon which means that while staying
> available, no updates or fixes will be released. Consider installing
> the newer prereleased cross-platform version of PnP PowerShell:
>
> Uninstall-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -AllVersions
> -Force Install-Module -Name PnP.PowerShell -AllowPrerelease
>
> Read more about the new cross-platform version of PnP PowerShell at
>
> https://pnp.github.io/powershell
>
> The new version of PnP PowerShell will be released as 1.0 in January
> 2021.

****The problem is that the [new module](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/) doesn't seem to include any of the *-PNPProvisioningTemplate cmdlets.****

**Anyone know how to apply a pnpprovisioning template now or has the cmdlets been renamed?**

There is also [a bug](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/2861) with the Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate cmdlet in the SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline module, that forces me to use a very old version 3.23.2007.1... But now I know that that bug will never be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look
https://github.com/pnp/powershell/issues/179#issuecomment-767683904
It states that you should use

```
Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate
```